# REMOVE upper Border layout

Tags: android

I have develop app in which I set layout `480 * 320`, it is starting from top. But my problem is there is one in build border are display when we take a new project and it is display in all `activity`. So I want to `disable` it.

Border like

[image: this]

So can you tell how can I remove it or hide it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is hide the **TitleBar** of the application. You can do that by changing the application theme.

Add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"` in the `<application>` tag of your manifest file.
Any theme with `.NoTitleBar` should do the trick.

Comment: @nik Didn't get you. Do you want the title bar to be black?

Comment: ya i want to title bar as black

Answer (score 1):

use any one.

Manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Or

java:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
requestFeature(FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

in you activity's `onCreate` before setting the layout should remove it.

Comment: **it's not** `requestFeature(FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`  

**its::**  

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

Answer (score 0):

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```